# How to set a new token when the token expired?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created the function `getNewToken`, in which I am fetching a new token on the basis of `refresh_token` and setting it in localstorage. Where to check the `Unauthorized 401` error and call this function `this.getNewToken()`?

```
if (error.status === 401) {
     this.getNewToken ();
}
```

---

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = localStorage.getItem('domain');

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    axios.defaults.baseURL = localStorage.getItem('domain');

    axios({
        url: "/api/v1/items",
        method: "GET"
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
          items: response.data,
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if(error.status === 401) {
            console.log(error.status);

            this.getNewToken();
        }
    })
  }

  getNewToken = () => {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = localStorage.getItem('domain');
    const url = '/api/refresh_token';

    const data = qs.stringify({
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_secret: ****,
      client_id: ****,
      refresh_token: ****
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }

    axios({ 
       method: 'post', 
       url, 
       data, 
       config
    }) 
    .then(res => { 
        if (res.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data))
          this.setState({
            token: res.data
          })

        } 
      }).catch(err => { 
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @Vencovsky I have no idea how to set up to catch the error 'Unautorised 401' for the whole application ?. In my case, it catches error 'Unautorised 401'  only when the component is rendered. To catch the error, I need to refresh the component

Comment: `In my case, it catches error 'Unautorised 401' only when the component is rendered` that makes sence because you are calling it in `componentDidMount`. What do you want to do? When you wan't to check the token?

Comment: @Vencovsky EXAMPLE: The token is valid for one hour. The application is turned on. I'm not doing anything for an hour. After an hour, I go to another component. Will the token be new?